# sharepoint 2013 term-driven page friendly url Using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint, taxonomy

How to get the term driven Page friendly url using jsom

`currentTerm.get_localCustomProperties()['_Sys_Nav_FriendlyUrlSegment'])`
// giving undefined

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the friendly URL you could utilize [`SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj994647.aspx#methods) which:

> Specifies navigation behavior and properties for a [`SP.Taxonomy.Term
>   constructor (sp.taxonomy)` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj857086.aspx) that is used to drive the
>   navigation and friendly URLs for a website.

The specified class contains [`getWebRelativeFriendlyUrl` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj954464.aspx) which

> returns the friendly URL segments as a concatenated path.

Example

```
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/15";

$.getScript(scriptbase +"/sp.runtime.js",function(){    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "/sp.publishing.js",function(){
            $.getScript(scriptbase+"/sp.taxonomy.js",function(){

                var termId = "--Term ID goes here--";


                var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);

                var term = taxSession.getTerm(termId);
                var navTerm = SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTerm.getAsResolvedByWeb(ctx,term, ctx.get_web(), "CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
                var friendlyUrl = navTerm.getWebRelativeFriendlyUrl();

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                   console.log(friendlyUrl.get_value());
                },
                function(sender,args) {
                   console.log(args.get_message());
                });
            })
        })
    })
});
```